# Can a generic in vb access shared data?

Tags: vb.net, generics

I want to do something like this:

```
public class X
  public shared some_text as string
  public sub do_something()
    ...
  end sub
end class

public class Y(of T as X)
  public shared function get_one() as T
    dim text=T.some_text
    ... whatever ...
  end function
end class
```

But "T.some_text" gives an error saying that I can't use T as a qualifier. Is there any way that I can access shared data or functions in T without creating an instance?

It appears I can say

```
dim dummy as new T()
dim text=dummy.some_text
```

I then get a warning that I shouldn't use an instance to access shared data, but I don't know how to access shared data WITHOUT creating an instance! :-(

Comment: If T is always X, you can do `X.some_text`

Comment: get_one() sets properties, it returns T, but T is always X, so why not just use the Constructor?

Comment: @jat My intent is that T could be a sub-type of X.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`some_text` is a shared member of `X`. So you have to write:

```
Dim text = X.some_text
```

If you want to access a shared member of `Y` (which is generic), you have to write:

```
Dim result = Y(Of X).get_one()
```

You can't access shared members through type parameters. Shared members don't follow the inheritance rules of instance members; they are static. You cannot override shared members (If you try to make a shared member overridable you get the compiler error: "*'Shared' cannot be combined with 'Overridable' on a method declaration.*"); therefore you must access them through the type that defined them. They are basically the same as module members; however, they must be qualified with the type name.

---

**UPDATE**

If you want to return different texts in different sub-types, use an overridable string property

```
Public Class X
    Public Overridable ReadOnly Property some_text() As String
        Get
            Return "x text"
        End Get
    End Property
End Class

Public Class Derived
    Inherits X
    Public Overrides ReadOnly Property some_text() As String
        Get
            Return "derived text"
        End Get
    End Property
End Class
```

Comment: My intent was that different sub-types of X could have different values for some_text. I guess you're saying that the answer is, You can't do that. Which is rather what I was afraid it was.

Comment: RE your update; Yeah, after I posted this question that solution occurred to me. The text has to be constant for that to work, but in my real case, it is. Well, I suppose it if it wasn't, the function could return the value of a shared variable, with a different shared variable in each subclass.

Comment: Yes it could return values of different shared variables or constants. (Constants are shared by default)

Answer (score 1):

You can't call methods on type parameters. Just do:

```
X.some_text
```

Answer (score 0):

`Shared` is basically `static`. It's not tied to an instance of a class and cannot be inherited or overridden or bound to a contract like an interface.

This means it is somewhat useless in terms of Generics and there is no built in functionality to access it. I think only VB allows accessing `Shared` members from the instance. Normal convention though is not access it from the instance, but from the class itself.

As @JAT mentions in the comment, you could just call `X.some_text` if your example is 1:1 of your actual setup.

Comment: My intent was that different sub-types of X could have different values, and I wanted to get to the value used for the sub-type given in the constructor for the generic object. I guess what folks are saying here is that that can't be done. Which is obviously not the answer I wanted to hear, but if that's what it is, oh well.